# zend studio auto add namespace not working

Tags: zend-studio, content-assist

i used

> The Zend Studio 10.6

,then upgrade it to

> 12.5

Now when i add new class it does not add namespace class in top of my code

for example:

```
 $test =  new test();
```

i must add

```
use project\Model\test;
```

in top of my code manually, but it must add this line automatically.
i active code assistant but problem not solved.
sincerely

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug,reported in zend studio forum
http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=126628